# Build ndk project with gradle. How to link static libraries?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm trying to build ndk project in Android studio with stable gradle plugin.

There is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "at.jku.ptam"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23

    ndk {
        moduleName "PTAM"
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments '-j9',
                    'APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a',
                    'NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
}
}
```

Android.mk file contains many includes of static libraries like this:

```
...
#prepare libcvd
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := cvd
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libcvd.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
...
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += cvd
```

I get error after build project

Error:(48, 23) fatal error: cvd/cvd.h: No such file or directory

All includes at cpp files are red

```
#include <cvd/image.h>
```

When I compile sources from command line with *ndk-buld* tool there is no problem and shared library compiled fine.

I think there is problem with build.gradle file. Maybe need to write paths to all .a libs into build.gradle file...

What could be the problem?